# getting error while installing osm(order & service management)

Tags: oracle

[image]

while installing `osm(order & service management)`after installing  `Oracle Database` and `Oracle WebLogic Server`, i am getting this error which is in the pic.

and in install log i am getting this below error.

> Caused by: com.mslv.install.db.util.DbManagerException: ORA-00600:
>   internal error code, arguments: [qkkCombine:1], [], [], [], [], [],
>   [], [], [], [], [], [] sql: alter table om_orch_item_hier add
>   CONSTRAINT XFK2OM_ORCH_ITEM_HIER   FOREIGN KEY (order_seq_id,
>   child_node_index)   REFERENCES OM_ORCH_ORDER_ITEM(order_seq_id,
>   item_node_index) ON DELETE CASCADE    NOT DEFERRABLE NORELY ENABLE
>   VALIDATENested Exception: ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments:
>   [qkkCombine:1], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [] Nested
>   Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00600: internal error code,
>   arguments: [qkkCombine:1], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
>
> at com.mslv.install.db.util.SqlHelper.execute(SqlHelper.java:202)   at
>   com.mslv.install.db.load.impl.AbstractObjectRootProxyImpl.processSqlStatement(AbstractObjectRootProxyImpl.java:399)
>     at
>   com.mslv.install.db.load.impl.AbstractObjectRootProxyImpl.processSql(AbstractObjectRootProxyImpl.java:388)
>     at
>   com.mslv.install.db.load.impl.AbstractObjectRootProxyImpl.processDDL(AbstractObjectRootProxyImpl.java:215)
>     at
>   com.mslv.install.db.load.impl.AbstractObjectRootProxyImpl.processObject(AbstractObjectRootProxyImpl.java:159)
>     at
>   com.mslv.install.db.processor.ApplicationProcessor.processCreateAction(ApplicationProcessor.java:577)
>     at
>   com.mslv.install.db.processor.ApplicationProcessor.processCreationActions(ApplicationProcessor.java:608)
>     at
>   com.mslv.install.db.processor.ApplicationProcessor.importApplicationItems(ApplicationProcessor.java:458)
>     at
>   com.mslv.install.db.processor.ApplicationProcessor.installApplicationModel(ApplicationProcessor.java:764)
>     at
>   com.mslv.install.db.processor.ApplicationProcessor.importApplicationModel(ApplicationProcessor.java:144)
>     at com.mslv.install.db.ImportDBTask.execute(ImportDBTask.java:39)
>     ... 14 more Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00600: internal
>   error code, arguments: [qkkCombine:1], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [],
>   [], [], []
>
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:439)    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:395)     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:802)   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436)  at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521)     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:194)    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:1000)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1307)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1882)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1847)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:301)
>     at com.mslv.install.db.util.SqlHelper.execute(SqlHelper.java:194)

Comment: Why does this question have the OpenStreetMap tag? This is obviously something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

The database has gone corrupt. Please re-install database and set all required parameters. The location of data files should not be too long. This seems to solve the problem for me when I faced the issue.